# multi account route53 public zone setup without prod prefix

Tags: amazon-web-services, dns, amazon-route53

I have a central aws account with a public zone `example.com` and two accounts for prod and dev environments. there are additional hosted zones in each of them for `prod.example.com` and `dev.example.com`.

Now i want to host a public webpage that is just accessible at `example.com` without the `prod` prefix. Where would i make the according entries?

Answer (score 2):

A hosted zone for `prod.example.com` or `dev.example.com` only has control of that specific subdomain. There is no way to create a record for the `example.com` root domain inside one of those subdomain hosted zones.

If you want to create a record for a website at `example.com` you have to create that record in the root `example.com` hosted zone.

Comment: aws allows the creation of hosted zones with the same name in multiple accounts. i was thinking of forwarding hosted zone example.com of the global account to hosted zone example.com of the prod account. Would that work?

Comment: AWS allows you to create as many hosted zones with the same name as you want, because they get to charge you the monthly fee for each one, but only one can actually work at a time. I'm not sure what you mean by "forwarding hosted zone".

Comment: With forwarding I mean an NS entry

Comment: I don't think you can "forward" one root domain DNS server (hosted zone) to another root domain DNS server. You just need to update the registrar to set a single hosted zone as the authoritative DNS server.